# PHP File Include

Tags: php, composer-php, include-path

I have searched the forums already, but none of the solutions have seemed to help me.

Basically I have just installed and created a package using composer. I need to autoload the classes, sounds pretty standard.

I followed all the instructions, and have added this line of code to my script:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

The vendor folder is located in the root folder of my server, here:

```
/root/vendor/autoload.php
```

So, I added

```
:/root
```

To my PHP ini file so that PHP searches in the root folder when looking for includes. I thought that should work but it's not :(

My PHP ini file now looks like this:

```
.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/root
```

The error message I am getting is this:

```
[14-Jul-2014 16:46:29 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/root') in /home/owned/public_html/trythis/ow_plugins/oftokbox/bol/service.php on line 38
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your webserver is not going to have permission for `/root`.  Why are you putting PHP files there?

Comment: You put files in `/root` ?!?!? Sounds like a bad idea...  Does the user that run the web server has access to `/root` ?

Comment: That's just where composer installed the vendor folder

Comment: I can uninstall it and re-install to another location, where would you recommend, I'm not that hot with UNIX!

Comment: do a <?php echo ini_get('include_path'); ?> and comment with the output. :)

these are the folders that require and include will turn to in the event of failure. you may need to use set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); in your index file to have it double check the root directory.

Comment: I have this: .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/root
Those other guys were saying I should probably move it out of root though, I just need to figure out now how to uninstall xomposer :S

Comment: this part: "So, I added `:/root`To my PHP ini file so that PHP searches in the root folder ..." it needs to include the full path with drive information i.e. `:C:\wamp\www`

Comment: That still doesn't work. Grr, I think those guys are right, it's to do with root folder permissions, but I don't know how to move the composer vendor folder.

Answer (score 1):

You implicitly state you are using Composer for a project. By doing so you must have a `composer.json` file somewhere. And Composer will create a vendor folder directly in the folder containing this file.

So if you also have a file `index.php` in the folder containing the `composer.json`, to include the autoloader you would use `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`.

If however you follow some security guidelines and have a dedicated folder containing public files, then the file would for example be called `public/index.php`, and for this file to reach the autoloader, the relative path would be `require '../vendor/autoload.php';`.

Composer cannot give a one-instructions-fits-all direction because it depends on which folder structure you have. But including the composer autoloader is just the same task as including any other file with a relative path.